# How to remove \n from a string?

Tags: python, string

Actually I am Scraping YouTube subtitles, It is working fine, but I cant remove the '\n'. I used `replace("\n", ' ')`, but it is not working.

**Here is the Code:**

```
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi
import re
remov = []
subtitles = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript('VW2VScHV7b4')
remov = re.sub(r", 'start': [0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?", '', str(subtitles))
remov = re.sub(r", 'duration': [0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?", '', remov)
remov = re.sub(r"'text': ", '', remov)
remov = re.sub(r"{", '', remov)
remov = re.sub(r"}", '', remov)
remov = remov.replace("\n", ' ')
remov = remov.replace("'", '')
finalsub = remov.replace('"', '')
finalsub = finalsub.replace('[Music], ', '')
finalsub = finalsub.replace('[', '')
finalsub = finalsub.replace(']', '')
finalsub = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])\d+\b', '', finalsub)
finalsub = re.sub('♪INTRO', '', finalsub)

print(finalsub)
```

Comment: You may need to replace `\\n` instead. As a tip, use `print(list(finalsub))`, so you can see exactly what character is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use `.rstrip('\r\n')` function

or

use `replace("\\n", " ")` instead of `replace("\n"," ")`